# Xcode 7 Archive Upload Error

Tags: xcode, upload, app-store, archive

Just wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error. I am trying to submit my app via, Xcode 7 -> Archive -> Submit to app store. I have validated the app and it has been approved. But when i try to submit it i keep getting this error. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting such issue you should check this points:

- First of all make sure on developer account Certificate & provisioning profiles are updated & not expired
- Once confirmed go to Xcode Menu -> Preferences -> Account
- Select your Account & click view details
- You will find your provisioning profile there, just remove it & download again than close it
- Now Set provisioning profile again in targets -> build settings, Clean project & than prepare new archive file
- Make sure you already submitted build previously & failed, so to use same version just go to Targets -> General & change Build no
- After that simply prepare new build & submit it

Hope it will guide you.